# Link to filtered Activities tab from Contact Summary? (Drupal 7, civicrm 4.7)

Tags: contacts, activities

I'd like to have a user click "View All Meeting Activities" from the contact summary front page and be shown the activities tab filtered by Activity Type "Meeting"

Is it going to be possible to pass the filter like that?

Thanks!

edit: i'm using Drupal 7 and civicrm 4.7

Comment: hi - can you confirm what CMS you are using, as there might be an easy Drupal solution but not for WP or J!

Comment: Hi, sorry - i've edited the question (Drupal 7, civicrm 4.7)

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this is to build a Drupal View based on CiviCRM Activities that is Filtered to show just the activities that you want for the logged in user and display that block on the civicrm home page.

If that sounds like the way to go and you are not familiar with Views, then add a comment and I can probably do an export of a View that might get you started.

Comment: Thanks - I wanted a more non-intrusive solution for this particular case (if i could pre-filter the activities tab, i could use the API to check whether certain types of activities were present, and provide links to see all of X from the summary page - "this contact has participated in meetings - see relevant activities >" etc )

However, i hadn't considered views for civicrm things, and your suggestion of a block of specific activity types for specific users is pretty appealing for other use cases! will certainly be giving that a go. I'm pretty familiar with views but thanks for the offer.

Comment: I think that using a View and setting the output so it shows as a Tab is a path that others have implemented. can't find link to it yet.

Comment: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2348/how-to-display-a-drupal-view-in-a-civicrm-tab